# Readline numbers as integers, not strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data list in a file that I am trying to mutate.
I want to change some of the data within the file, but wherever there is a digit in the list, it returns it as a string. If I wanted to return another integer back to the list so when I re-read it back, it will be in int, can I just use `int(10)`, for example, `10` and not `"10"`? As it seems readlines turns everything into a str.

Comment: `How can I have it in my main code` where is your main code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. After reading the file using:

```
file = open(“testfile.text”, “r”) 
file.read()
```

you can store the text of the file in a string.
To convert a string to int, you must use `int(string_name)` to convert it into a string.
For more information of the topic, refer to the documentations:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int